# Scheduler Get Data From SQL Server to Oracle

Tags: sql-server, oracle

I want create a task as scheduler to get Data From SQL Server 2000 to Oracle ? 
how i can do it ? thanks

Comment: What sort of skills does the group responsible for this task have? Oracle, or SQL Server, or both? Do you currently use a particular task scheduler?

Answer (score 1):

This kind of processes are called ETL automation.

1. You should first write appropriate code accomplish the data transformation and extraction prior loading to other system. You have several options. One of them is using SQL. You may use either oracle to get data from SQL server or vice versa.
2. It is better to convert this code to a batch executable to able to run from command line.
3. Choose a scheduler to execute the job according to your business requirements.

Alternatives are cron for ux platforms, windows task scheduler for ms platforms, open source frameworks to implement your own (like quartz), open source products if you do not have budget or more professional commercial ones like TlosLite.

Comment: Why should the data transformation be performed prior to loading to the target system? Why is it better to convert the code to a batch executable?

Comment: If it **necessary** you should do transfromation or use some kind of ETL tools. Also if it is again **necessary**, to make your task portable and manageable it is better to convert it to batch/sh file. Of course you have an option to execute your task as program alternatively.

Answer (score 0):

In Sql server you can create DTS job to transfer the data from SQL server table to Oracle table.Later using SQL server Agent,you can schedule this job.